# how to store a value in Phonegap apps, any way other than database

Tags: cordova, nsuserdefaults, sharedpreferences

I am a mobile developer. So far I have worked on iPhone and Android apps. Now I am working on Phone gap based apps for iPhone and Android mobiles.

Now my problem is in my app I have a login page where I have to enter the username and password. After a successful login, I return a unique token which I have to use for the whole app. If the app gets closed and opened after a long time I want this to remain the same.

For this in ios apps we use a method called `UserDefault` method and whereas in Android apps we have a default method called `SharedPreference`. In that way is there any default method for Phonegap or I have to use only the database.

Currently, I am writing a `JavaScript` for my phone gap apps, please give me any suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is local storage. [Here](http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/home/start/twominutetutorials/tmt4p3) is a tutorial on using local storage with PhoneGap.