# Saving text values in javascript like NSUserdefaults which is in iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

I would like to ask one question. I am new to Javascript, cordova application. I want to save User(Login) details like  NSUserDefaults which is in iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [data storage](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.4.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html) (or directly with the SQLite library) or also with local storage as explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7721614/how-to-store-a-value-in-phonegap-apps-any-way-other-than-database)

Comment: However, please consider to flag the accepted answers, it's always pleasant for those who answer and it can help the readings of the posts for others ;)

Comment: I am going through this document. I will do it later. Please vote up my question :)